# How can I know the URL that the user clicked on while the page is loading?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

Sometimes we click on links before the page has fully loaded. It turns out that there’s no reliable way of knowing what the link that the user click is. You might say that it’s safe to look at the delegate method:

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType;
```

But, as some of my experiments have shown there are calls to this method with UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked more than once for the same page.

For example, try logging this path:

1. Go to google.com.
2. Search for "new york times".
3. Click on the first link.

At step (3) the delegate get’s called 3 times! with UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked. First, when you click the link to go to nytimes.com from google and then two more times while it’s loading. **In-sane!**

I’ve gone to the extreme for this. I remade my entire project in iOS 8 hoping that the new [WKWebView](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/WebKit/Reference/WKWebView_Ref/index.html) would provide a solution but it turned out it worked the same way.

I figured out a solution but I really can’t tell wether it will work or not every time the user clicks a link while the page is loading.

Here it is:

When you click a link to go to another page the delegate get’s called with this method:

```
- (void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error;
```

The error is:

```
"The operation couldn’t be completed.” (-999)
```

The last link that the UIWebView loads before the error is thrown is the new link that the user clicked on. So, if you store every link that the UIWebView loads in a variable named lastURL you can use the lastURL as the new page’s URL.

Two things I worry about:

1. The delegate get’s called to report the error with a slight delay allowing a few sub frames of the new web page to load resulting in the lastURL to store the URL of some sub frame of the new link and not the actual new link.
2. The error -999 is thrown for some other issue and not when the page has failed loading because the user clicked a link.

Is there a more reliable way? I don't care if your way works for iOS 7 or iOS 8.